# Upper bound of a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-integration, upper-lower-bounds

Working with a class of polynomials I've found this integral

$$A_n(x)=\frac{n!}{2\pi\,i}\int_C\frac{e^{x\,(e^t-1)}}{t^{n+1}}dt$$
where $C$ h is a closed circuit described in the positive sense surrounding the
origin.

I wonder if it's possible find a upper bound of this integral (depending on $n$)

Comment: I'd suggest using $z$ in place of $t$, as $t$ is more commonly a real parameter (this is a matter of taste, of course). Do you know about Cauchy's Estimates?

Answer (score 1):

Using the residue theorem, we find that

$$\begin{align}
A_n(x)&=e^{-x}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{xe^t}\\\\
&=e^{-x}\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{xe^t}B_{n,k}(xe^t, xe^t, \dots, xe^t)\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}(x,x, \dots, x)\\\\
&=B_n(x,x,\dots,x)\\\\
&=T_n(x)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \brace k} x^k
\end{align}$$

where $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$ are the Bell polynomials, $B_n(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)$ is the $n$th complete exponential Bell polynomial, $T_n(x)$ is the Touchard polynomial, and ${n \brace k}$ are Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: Yes, these polynomials are the Touchard polynomials. But what I looking for is a bound of them.

Comment: What do you mean by a "bound" for them?  Polynomials are not bounded.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I mean an expression (depending on $n$) greater than them and as fine as possible

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here?  Are you looking for a large $x$ or a large $n$ asymptotic approximation?

Comment: I'm looking for an expression $f(n)$ bigger than $A_n(x)$ for all $x$: $$A_n(x)\leq f(n)\,\,\,\,\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Inasmuch as polynomials are unbounded, there is no such $f(n)$ that bounds $A_n(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then $f$ also depending on $x$, that is,$$A_n(x)\leq f(n,x)$$

Comment: Then, let $f(n,x)=A_n(x)+1$

Comment: The problem is that this bound $f(n,x)$ will be put in a infinite sum and must be an expresion that I be able to sum. As I don't know the value of $\sum A_n$ ,$ \sum A_n +1$ neither.Apollogies if I don't write a good explanation of the problem, my English is not good.

Comment: Do you really want to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n(x)$?  That series diverges.

Comment: No, this is not the series.

Comment: What is the series?

Comment: @popi Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Partially: I have not found a bound for Touchard polynomial but solved the problem that involved them

Comment: Well, polynomials are not bounded.  But I'm pleased to hear that you solved the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry !! I thought I had already voted for you.

Comment: Thank you. And feel free to also accept the answer.

Comment: Touchard polynomials are also called exponential polynomials in literature.
(1) F. Qi, Some inequalities and an application of exponential polynomials, Math. Inequal. Appl. 23 (2020), 123--135; https://doi.org/10.7153/mia-2020-23-10. (2) F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and B.-N. Guo, Some properties and an application of multivariate exponential polynomials, Math. Methods Appl. Sci. 43 (2020), no. 6, 2967--2983; https://doi.org/10.1002/mma.6095. (3) F. Qi, Some inequalities for the Bell numbers, Proc. Indian Academy Sci. Math. Sci. 127 (2017), 551--564; https://doi.org/10.1007/s12044-017-0355-2.